# Is Constraints necessary for tvos app?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I am new to Apple TV apps development. I have designed few views on storyboard, which is looking nice on Apple TV simulator, but some control's edges are cutting when I am running it on HDMI monitor and actual tv.

I want to know, if constraints are needed to manage UI for different sizes of Tvs? If no, is there any standard Apple has introduced to manage this part?

Comment: highly recommended to build up the layout by using constraints properly.

Comment: Not necessary as of now, but what would happen if Apple were to release dual screen apps on the Apple TV? Sounds like a long day of fixing something that could've been avoided by using constraints originally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Autolayout is recommended, but not required. However, it's a good chance this isn't your issue. If you're developing a tvOS app, be aware that there is a safe area you need to work with. Many TV's (including some new HDTV's) will cut the edges of the screen off (this is called overscan). The safe area is the part of the screen in the centre that you should ensure all of your important content is in.

So, for a tvOS app, you should set up your views with the dimensions of 1920x1080, but keep all of your important content, buttons, text etc, inside the centre 1740x960 region. This leaves 90px borders on the sides, and 60px borders on the top and bottom. Those borders should of course still have non-important information, such as your background images etc.

See here for more details: https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/#layout

Comment: You may want to update this answer to account for Apple's addition of the Safe Area to tvOS in tvOS 11. The Safe Area accounts for overscan on a wide range of devices and should be safe to constrain your views to that.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints are not mandatory, but they can save you a lot of trouble. Furthermore, actually constraints(auto layout) are how Apple wants developers to manage the app for different resolutions.

Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html

If you are new to constraints, I also found this tutorial helpful: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-tvos-development--cms-24848

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is not mandatory for any kind of development whether is ios, tvos or watchos. we have option in `file inspector` to disable autolayout that means it is not necessary. But if you use autolayout it can make your task too much easy.

Not using autolayout does make the assumption that your app will never run at any other resolution, but more importantly, autolayout is very helpful when it comes down to dealing with things other than overall screen size, such as localization of text and buttons etc.

If you use autolayout then it can help you in future release of tvos of different screensize.

Hope this will help :)